# Cheerio - How to get corresponding dd tag from each dt line

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Have some problem with Cheerio and finding the right syntax to solve my problem.

```
    <section class="panel">
<dl class="definition-list definition-list--inline">
    <dt>Sektor</dt>
        <dd>Privat</dd>
    <dt>Sted</dt>
        <dd>Øvre Banegate 28, 4014 Stavanger</dd>
    <dt>Bransje</dt>
        <dd>Arkitektur, areal og interiør,</dd>
        <dd>Bygg og anlegg,</dd>
        <dd>Konsulent og rådgivning</dd>
        <dt>Stillingsfunksjon</dt>
        <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging / Arealplanlegger,</dd>
        <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging / Arkitekt,</dd>
        <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging</dd>
        </dl>
</section>
```

I need to find the right syntax to get the dd's after the right dt. I got it right with Puppeteer but I dont manage to get it right with Cheerio.
So far I have done

```
$('body > main > div > div.grid > div.grid__unit.u-r-size2of3 > div > section:nth-child(9) > dl dd').each(function(i, elem) {
    const titleNode = $(elem);
    const titleText = titleNode.text();
    
    titleList5.push(titleText);
  });
```

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with an array of `<dd>`s for each `<dt>`.

```js
const map = new Map();
let group;

$('.panel dl.definition-list').children().each((i, elem) => {
  switch (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "dt":
      // start a list for this <dt>
      map.set(elem, group = []);
      break;

    case "dd":
      // add <dd> to the list for the current <dt>; if there is one.
      group?.push(elem);
      break;

    default:
      // just in case; 
      // anyways, where would <dd>s belong that are after something else than a <dt>?
      // ignore them
      group = null;
  }
});

console.log(...map.entries());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="panel">
  <dl class="definition-list definition-list--inline">
    <dt>Sektor</dt>
    <dd>Privat</dd>

    <dt>Sted</dt>
    <dd>Øvre Banegate 28, 4014 Stavanger</dd>

    <dt>Bransje</dt>
    <dd>Arkitektur, areal og interiør,</dd>
    <dd>Bygg og anlegg,</dd>
    <dd>Konsulent og rådgivning</dd>

    <dt>Stillingsfunksjon</dt>
    <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging / Arealplanlegger,</dd>
    <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging / Arkitekt,</dd>
    <dd>Arkitekt og planlegging</dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This answer solved my problem, and other problem with getting the dds after dt :)

Answer (score 1):

With nextUntil since there's more than one and they're siblings:

```
let data = $('dt').get().reduce((acc, dt, i) => {
  let key = $(dt).text()
  let value = $(dt).nextUntil('dt').get().map(dl => $(dl).text())
  acc[key] = value
  return acc
}, {})
```